# How to not affect UV while editing geometry?

Tags: uv, snapping

I want to move an edge to a precise point and I don't want to affect the uv.
So I use Shit+E Edge Slide or the command Shift+V (same for vertex I guess).
But I can't snap to a vertex. The point where I want to bring the edge is on the grid.

I'm making pieces of walls. I just want to copy my wall and add a window, a door etc, without affecting the uv.

Comment: As far as I know this isn't supported in Blender, either you get precision modeling snapping, or you get undistorted UVs, not both at the same time.

Comment: Thx for the answer! How and where can I make a feedback on that to improve Blender ?

Comment: You can try [RightClick-Select](https://rightclickselect.com/). Make sure you search before posting if there aren't any previous requests for the same functionality